# Firefox - "open with" does not open the application and opens the /tmp folder

Tags: firefox, 15.04

I have ubuntu 15.04 and firefox 39.0.
When I click on a link, e.g. to download a PDF file, firefox asks to download or open with the default system application, if I choose `open with [application]` the `/tmp` folder opens and the file is not opened with the default application as I wanted.

Do you know anything abount this? How can I solve it?

Thanks

Comment: You could enter the URL `about:preferences#applications` in your Firefox and check whether there are any unusual entries/options selected in the list of applications as a first step. I'm looking for more detailed configuration files etc...

Comment: I looked, but could not find anything I can work with yet... :-/

Comment: I tried that, but I could not find anything unusual.